# proximity alert tutorial

Tags: java, android

I have followed a tutorial about how to use the proximity alert and how to register it.
But what do they mean by this part of code given below

```
private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.javacodegeeks.android.lbs.ProximityAlert";
```

The code is run but the notification does not appear.

Comment: Any link to this tutorial ?

Comment: this is a bit brief.... plz always share the code and detail what you tried

Answer (score 0):

Based on the several tutorials I've found online about the topic, that's the custom Intent action that will be fired as a proximity alert.
Your app should implement a receiver with that intent filter, to react properly.